# Plotting dates on the x-axis in m/d/Y format

Tags: python-3.x

I want to generate a graph plot in which I would like to display date as "01/03/1991" format but with my code I am getting the date as "Jan 03 1991".
Below is the code I am using to generate the graph. Can anybody help me fix this issue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = ['01/02/1991','01/03/1991','01/04/1991', '01/05/1991','01/06/1991','01/07/1991']

a = [0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 10.0]
r = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%m/%d/%Y').date() for d in dates]
s = [1.0, 4.0, 9.0, 16.0, 25.0, 40.0]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
lns1 = ax1.plot(r, a, marker='o', label='No. of trip', linewidth=4)
lns2 = ax2.plot(r, s, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='r', label='No. of customer', linewidth=4)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y1', color='b')
ax2.set_ylabel('y2', color='r')

# added these three lines
lns = lns1+lns2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax2.legend(lns, labs, loc=0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your applying the formatter to the wrong object.  You should be applying it to

```
ax1
```

like so

```
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Comment: yes I did like that previously but it gave me error. Now i have fixed it. Thank you very much